# C# Creating your own hash algorithm - 99 documents, 0.0001 collision?

Tags: c#, cryptography

Looking at [Wolfram: collision to bits - graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1%20-%20E%5E(-(99)%5E2%2F(2*2%5Ex)),%20%7Bx,%2024,%2026%7D%5D) with 99 documents, I'd need a 25.5bit hashing algorithm to have a 0.0001 chance for a collision.

I looked at CRC-24 and I was wondering if it could be improved to use even less characters. I have a big list of characters that can be used for the hash: Basically all Unicode characters except for 4 or 5 characters.

**Now how do you create your own hash algorithm based on a set of usable characters in C#?**

EDIT:

I try to precise the issue: I have 99 strings. I want to cut them to 64 chars max. length. This can create duplicates. But they need to be unique while maintaining their meaning. The idea was to create a hash as small as possible and replace the last characters with the hash created of the original string. The hash of course should have a low probability for collision and be as short as possible. How I understand, the more symbols can be used in the hash (as in a-z0-9 or a-zA-Z0-9 or even all unicode characters), the less characters can the hash have before there are collisions. I looked at sha-1 and just trimming it, or crc-32 but they are not using the "full potential" of unicode characters.

Comment: Why is this tagged `Cryptography`? Do you need a cryptographic hash? CRC hashes are not cryptographic. Are you trying to create a new hash, or do you want to encode an existing hash using your special characters?

Comment: Can you say more about what you're doing here? You are talking about CRC, which is an error-detection protocol, but you have tagged your question with "crypto", which leads me to believe that you have some false beliefs about hash algorithms that might be preventing you from being successful.  Can you expand on the question with more details?

Comment: Just take a Cryptographic hash function as SHA2, SHA3, blake2b,... and trim to your required size

Comment: @kelalaka: The problem is that we do not know what use case the original poster has for this hash function; for example, (1) truncated crypto strength hash functions may have such poor performance that they make performance worse than an algorithm that collides more, (2) truncated crypto functions collide basically at random; a well-designed error detection collides less often on common mutations such as single-bit-flip.  This is not a trivial question and we have not been given nearly enough information to answer it.

Comment: For non-crypto hashing, I like the [FNV hash function](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/), which is fast and comes in a lot of sizes.

Comment: I tagged it Cryptography cause "hashing" was mentioned in its description. I will update the description above to be more precise.